# How can I find out which function call is corrupting my data?

Tags: delphi, debugging

in Delphi 7 , declared an class and created a class from it, (in the uml meaning).

the class contains a public field type of stringlist.

after passing the object a few times, the first letter in the first row is trimed out.

how do i trace it from not happening???

the function calling that trims is

```
stringlist.ValueFromIndex[i];
```

more information?

well its something like this.

```
type 
  TObjectionFilterFields = class(TObject)
  private
    public
      z,x,c,v,b,n,a,s:integer;
      list1:TStringList;
      list2:TStringList;
      enum:TEnum;
      constructor Create; //override;
      destructor Destroy; //override;
  end;
```

now at one object we invoke create, and insert data, and pass it on.
on another object we grab the data and create a string out of it, with + concatination.

```
for i := 0 to list1.count-1
 sql.add(''''+list1.ValueFromIndex[i] + ''''+'hdsjkf');
```

envoking stringlist.Strings[i] solved it

thanks

Comment: Can you please give some more information, and preferably some code.

Comment: Can you tell us what the name/value pair is? The missing character isn't the name/value separator is it? Usually it's an equal sign (=). Later versions of Delphi let you set it via TStrings.NameValueSeparator but I don't know if that existed in D7. You could check the raw string using stringlist[i] (should see something like "Name=Value").

Comment: I assume "for i= to list1.count-1" needs to be "for i= **0** to list1.count-1"

Comment: yes im java programmer. its syntax hell for me. sorry

Comment: Use AnsiQuotedStr() to quote your string properly....

Comment: thanks ldsandon, that was a very good tip. ill use it from now on.

Comment: @None, copying and pasting does not lead to syntax hell. Copy and paste *real code*, and you won't waste time dealing with confused people on Stack Overflow who only want to help, but who have no idea what you're dealing with because you haven't shown them something that demonstrates the problem. Re-typing a problem into a text box only serves to introduce *new* errors that distract everyone from the problem you actually have.

Comment: @Rob the code is too complex. it involves huge classes that are not relevant. claiming syntax hell, is minor complaining on my side from converting from c style to pascal style .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand. You have an object that contains a public field of the type TStringList.

```
type
  TMyClass = class
    FField : TStringList;
  end;
```

You have created an instance and passed it to a function.

```
var
  instance : TMyClass;

begin
  instance := TMyClass.Create;
  try
    DoSomething(instance);
  finally
    instance.Free;
  end;
end;


procedure DoSomething(AObject: TMyClass);
begin
  // Check here
  DoSomethingElse(AObject);
  // Check here
end;

procedure DoSomethingElse(AObject: TMyClass);
begin
  // Check here
end;
```

You can check the state of the object at each entry and exit point of each function so you find out when the change occurs. Post that code if you cannot find the problem yourself.

Please note that using public fields can be dangerous, because anything can access and change that field.

Comment: i started with record however i found it there are problems passing the value of String . so i gave up on that idea, and modifying the encapsulation with successors will take some work.